# Using phpmailer with SMTP for my web application

Tags: php, phpmailer

I am building a website with PHP for a client. The website has a contact form, so I added the `phpmailer` class to be able to send the contact form details to the client's mail address.

Now, when I configure the `phpmailer` class, I have to provide the SMTP server username and password (I used smtp.gmail.com). I highly doubt that my client will give me his gmail credentials.

When I use the `phpmailer` class without enabling SMTP configuration (i.e not giving `$mail->isSMTP()` and the relevant configurations that follows it), I get the message marked as `SPAM` in my inbox. I can't use the php mail function because I want to format the body of the email as a template with HTML and CSS.

Is there a way I can use the `phpmailer` class(no SMTP) without getting the email marked as SPAM? or Is there any other solution for the problem I am facing?

Comment: Not configuring SMTP in PHPMailer merely shifts the issue to your local MTA (sendmail), which needs configuration then,

Answer (score 0):

Emails sent by phpmailer being marked as SPAM is a much more complex issue.  You might find a good explanation:

[phpMailer gmail spam](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16900641/phpmailer-gmail-spam)

Even the GitHub of PHP Mailer also has this discussion:

https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/issues/111

There are also quite a few search results on Google, regarding this topic.